# VB.NET Parsing values from Steam web API response

Tags: vb.net, steam-web-api

I downloaded this JSON response from Steam web API calling the url this way:

```vb
Dim sourceJSON As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.steampowered.com/IPublishedFileService/GetDetails/v1/?key=MYSTEAMWEBAPIKEY&includevotes=false&includechildren=true&publishedfileids[0]=3086551849")
```

This is the JSON response:

```json
{
  "response": {
    "publishedfiledetails": [
      {
        "result": 1,
        "publishedfileid": "3086551849",
        "creator": "76561197998867693",
        "creator_appid": 766,
        "consumer_appid": 730,
        "consumer_shortcutid": 0,
        "filename": "1700252325_new_preview_maxresdefault.jpg",
        "file_size": "58831",
        "preview_file_size": "58831",
        "file_url": "https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/2205136466808259480/2A0C6878ACB04B70B5522B480B7E77A984103704/",
        "preview_url": "https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/2205136466808259480/2A0C6878ACB04B70B5522B480B7E77A984103704/",
        "url": "",
        "hcontent_file": "2205136466808259480",
        "hcontent_preview": "2205136466808259480",
        "title": "Mapas AWP",
        "file_description": "Rotación de mapas AWP",
        "time_created": 1701437080,
        "time_updated": 1701863226,
        "visibility": 0,
        "flags": 2115072,
        "workshop_file": false,
        "workshop_accepted": false,
        "show_subscribe_all": false,
        "num_comments_developer": 0,
        "num_comments_public": 0,
        "banned": false,
        "ban_reason": "",
        "banner": "76561197960265728",
        "can_be_deleted": true,
        "app_name": "Counter-Strike 2",
        "file_type": 2,
        "can_subscribe": false,
        "subscriptions": 0,
        "favorited": 0,
        "followers": 0,
        "lifetime_subscriptions": 0,
        "lifetime_favorited": 0,
        "lifetime_followers": 0,
        "lifetime_playtime": "0",
        "lifetime_playtime_sessions": "0",
        "views": 6,
        "image_width": 1280,
        "image_height": 720,
        "num_children": 7,
        "num_reports": 0,
        "tags": [
          {"tag": "Classic","display_name": "Classic"},
          {"tag": "Demolition","display_name": "Demolition"},
          {"tag": "Deathmatch","display_name": "Deathmatch"},
          {"tag": "Custom","display_name": "Custom"},
          {"tag": "Armsrace","display_name": "Armsrace"},
          {"tag": "Training","display_name": "Training"},
          {"tag": "Co-op Strike","display_name": "Co-op Strike"},
          {"tag": "Wingman","display_name": "Wingman"},
          {"tag": "Flying Scoutsman","display_name": "Flying Scoutsman"},
          {"tag": "Cs2","display_name": "CS2"}
        ],
        "children": [
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3070290869**",
            "sortorder": 2,
            "file_type": 0
          },
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3072667387**",
            "sortorder": 1,
            "file_type": 0
          },
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3094676284**",
            "sortorder": 3,
            "file_type": 0
          },
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3097084578**",
            "sortorder": 4,
            "file_type": 0
          },
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3075511506**",
            "sortorder": 5,
            "file_type": 0
          },
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3076554807**",
            "sortorder": 6,
            "file_type": 0
          },
          {
            "publishedfileid": "**3088944650**",
            "sortorder": 7,
            "file_type": 0
          }
        ],
        "language": 0,
        "maybe_inappropriate_sex": false,
        "maybe_inappropriate_violence": false,
        "revision_change_number": "1",
        "revision": 1,
        "available_revisions": [2],
        "ban_text_check_result": 5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to extract the numbers in bold... that is, all the `response.publishedfiledetails[0].children[*].publishedfileid` values. But i haven't enough skill working with VB.NET and JSON.

How can I do this?

Comment: That response is `JSON`, not XML. There's a significant difference so hopefully this should help with your searching. I'd also recommend looking into `Newtonsoft.Json` for parsing this and working with it like normal objects

Comment: Also, when adding code to a question, it is customary to wrap it in three backticks ("`"). This tells StackOverflow that it is code and it formats it appropriately :)